# Java Is there a way to generate a hashcode() for a unique equals case?

Tags: java

Say I have 3 objects A, B, & C.

Object A is equal to object B & object C. But, objects B & C are **NOT** equal. Is it possible to have a hashcode() method that supports this concept ?

To give you a real example of this type of use case say I have this object structure

```
class MyObject {
  String id;
  // .. other fields
}
```

MyObject A has an id = "override".

MyObject B has an id = "1".

MyObject C has an id = "2".

The idea is that there is a special case whenever the id of "override" is found that it immediately overrides any & all other MyObject's because we only want that 1 single object. However, MyObject B & C don't have this "override" id therefore those objects should not be considered "equal".

Comment: Your equals is broken. Equality is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Thus from A = B and A = C follows B = C.

Comment: I thought so. I wanted a convenient way to handle these types of objects when dealing with collections such as Sets so that I would have to reiterate over all of the elements everytime i want to add a new one in order to check this whole overriding concept

Comment: @turbofood That clearly sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do not implement `equals()` (and `hashcode()`) that way, that it breaks the contract of the [`java.lang.Object.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method.

Comment: I was just going to say the same, XY Problem. Don't ask how to implement your mistaken solution to your problem, ask about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this. In your `equals` method, just short-circuit with a check for "override".

```java
if (this.id.equals("override")) return true;
```

#### Full example

```java
public class Question_74158193 {
    public static String OVERRIDE = "override";
    
    static class MyObject {
        private String id;
        public MyObject(String id) { this.id = id; }
        public MyObject() { this(OVERRIDE); }
        public String getId() { return id; }
      
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 31 * hash + (id == null || id.equals(OVERRIDE) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
            return hash;
        }
      
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null) return false;
            if (this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            if (this.id.equals(OVERRIDE)) return true;
            MyObject myObj = (MyObject) o;
            return id.equals(myObj.id);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject
            a = new MyObject(),
            b = new MyObject("1"),
            c = new MyObject("2"),
            d = new MyObject();
         
        System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true
        System.out.println(a.equals(c)); // true
        System.out.println(b.equals(c)); // false
        
        System.out.println(a.hashCode()); // 217 - matches d
        System.out.println(b.hashCode()); // 266
        System.out.println(c.hashCode()); // 267
        System.out.println(d.hashCode()); // 217 - matches a
     }
}
```